# rendering partial view without refreshing the main view in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I have a Main view like below

```
@model pjct.Models.Main_Model
 @using (Html.BeginForm("main_view", "pjct", FormMethod.Post)) 
  {
   //main form details

   @Html.Partial("partial_view", @Model.partial_model)
   //main form details


}
```

When the form render for first time the partial view model will be blank..
In the main view there is a textbox..When its value got changed an ajax call will occurred and generate a model for partial view. I don't have an idea hw to pass that model to partial and render it without refreshing the main view.

Ajax call to create partial model

```
 $("#services").on('change', '#code', function () {

                ($("#code").val() != '' && $("#code").val() != null);
                {
                    var code = $("#code").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '../main/get_price',
                        data: { c_code: code },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            });


public ActionResult get_price(string c_code)
{

 //generate the model for partial view and need to call the same.
}
```

How can i achieve the same..I am new to this partial model and not getting an idea.

Comment: Your `get_price()` method need to return the `partial_view.cshtml` partial (e.g. `return PartialView("partial_view", model);` and then you update the DOM in the ajax success callback - e.g. `$(someElement).html(data);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `someElement` means a div or something??

Comment: Yes, you could add a (say) `<div id="partial">@Html.Partial("partial_view", @Model.partial_model)</div>` to the view and use `$('#partial').html(data);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks..let me try and get back to u

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to render the partial view because the partial model don't have any relation with the Main view model

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. You already have `@Html.Partial("partial_view", @Model.partial_model)` so there must be a relationship (although you have not shown either of your models or what the partial view is)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170982/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).